# unable to run django app using foreman and gunicorn

Tags: django, heroku, foreman

I am trying to run my django app using gunicorn and foreman. I can successfully run it using `python manage.py server`. However when running it using forman it fails -

```
15:32:01 web.1  | started with pid 29188
15:32:01 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:01 [29191] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
15:32:01 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:01 [29191] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (29191)
15:32:01 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:01 [29191] [INFO] Using worker: sync
15:32:01 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:01 [29194] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29194
15:32:01 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:01 [29194] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29194)
15:32:02 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:02 [29191] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
15:32:02 web.1  | 2012-08-16 15:32:02 [29191] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
15:32:02 web.1  | exited with code 3
```

Below is the contents of the Procfile -

```
web: gunicorn tms.wsgi
```

I have been following the instructions given on heroku for setting it up.

Answer (score 4):

What instructions are you following? I run Django apps on Heroku using this:

```
web: python django_project/manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3 -k gevent --preload
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was unable to run it on my local system. The above error came when trying to run it on my ubuntu PC. Are you able to run the above command with foreman locally too ?

Comment: This one worked for me. Thank you. Earlier it was telling me that it couldn't find the wsgi module even though I added all folders surrounding it to the PYTHONPATH and to the PATH....

Answer (score 0):

What directory is your settings.py file located in in which you added `'gunicorn'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`? I'm assuming you're following the Heroku Getting Started with Django tutorial. The .wsgi file you state in your `Procfile` should match with that directory which you have your settings.py in.

Your `Procfile` should be:

```
    web: gunicorn <directory_containing_settings.py_file>.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing trouble following the Heroku Documentation then you may check my sample app deployed to Heroku https://github.com/shinigamiryuk/Django-Heroku-Sample-Application